# Tem sequências de caracteres ​no meu executável que não pus no fonte

Tags: c, compilação

Eu compilo um programa muito simples, que não tem literais de string. Apenas lida com matemática.

Aí, ao examinar o conteúdo do do executável eu veja coisas assim, mesmo que eu não tenha digitado nada parecido no meu código:

> crtstuff.cderegister_tm_clones__do_global_dtors_auxcompleted.7697__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entryframe_dummy__frame_dummy_init_array_entryGame.cASlash__FRAME_END____init_array_end_DYNAMIC__init_array_start__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE___libc_csu_finigetenv@@GLIBC_2.2.5_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTablestrcpy@@GLIBC_2.2.5ConfigDataputs@@GLIBC_2.2.5_edatastrlen@@GLIBC_2.2.5__stack_chk_fail@@GLIBC_2.4__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5__data_start__gmon_start____dso_handle_IO_stdin_used__libc_csu_init__bss_startmainstrcat@@GLIBC_2.2.5__TMC_END___ITM_registerTMCloneTable__cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5.symtab.strtab.shstrtab.interp.note.ABI-tag.note.gnu.build-id.gnu.hash.dynsym.dynstr.gnu.version.gnu.version_r.rela.dyn.rela.plt.init.plt.got.text.fini.rodata.eh_frame_hdr.eh_frame.init_array.fini_array.dynamic.data.bss.comment

O código compilado deveria ser apenas instruções brutas, então, por que todas as strings?

E nomes de variáveis ​​globais são armazenados. Também por que os nomes de variáveis ​​são armazenados se são variáveis ​​globais?

Comment: Existe a flag e o comando "strip" na maior parte dos "kits" de compilador C, que remove a maior parte das informações de _debug_. Além disso, tem coisas que fazem parte da biblioteca padrão (stdlib), que contém as funções essenciais que seu programa pode usar. Tem mais coisas também, que servem para estruturar o executável para a plataforma alvo, além de outras referências para o linker, dependendo de como gerou (mas só quis adiantar o assunto, até que alguem responda mais extensivamente).

Comment: Tem como colocar o código, versão do compilador e comando utilizado para compilar ?

Comment: São informações usadas pelo linker. Geralmente, sobre nomes de variáveis e funções, alocação de memória, debug. etc.